# Control one video when start playing another video in javascript

Tags: javascript, video

I have a page with two videos where the both videos are playing together. What I am doing is I am playing one video and I am playing another video without pausing previous one. Now, what I want is, the previous video should be paused when we are start playing another video. Please help in this regards. This should be taggle...

Comment: can us give us the code what you have tried.

Comment: I didn't tried yet and I am blank about it...

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<video class="video" autobuffer controls>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video class="video" autobuffer controls>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.video').on('play', function () {
    $('.video').not($(this).get(0)).each(function () {
        $(this).get(0).pause(); //Stops all videos except the current
    });
});
```

[DEMO jQuery](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VAFa6/)

**without jQuery**

```
//add Event listener for all videos
var videos = document.getElementsByClassName('video');
for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++){
    videos[i].addEventListener('playing', function(){ //on "play"...
        controlVideos(this);  //..call controlVideos
    });
};

function controlVideos(current){
  for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++){
      if( videos[i] != current) videos[i].pause();  //stop video if it's not the current 
  }
}
```

[DEMO without jQuery](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VAFa6/1/)

Comment: It is working exactly what I expected... Thanks alexP.. Thanks again